# Поиск игнорируя ненужные символы

Tags: mysql

У меня в базе записаны телефоны в поле типа varchar, то есть там могут быть не только цифры, но и всякие знаки скобки, дефисы и т.п. Я хочу найти в этом поле телефон делая запрос без знаков. Например в базе есть 555-333, я хочу по 5553 найти этот телефон.

Comment: Полнотекстовый поиск это всегда медленно. В mysql есть [regexp](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp)

Я бы на самом деле посоветовал вам изменить способ хранения телефона.

Comment: @eicto, it depend. В общем случае пользовательские данные лучше хранить как есть, без изменений. А вот при вставке или редактировании автоматически генерить соседнее поле, где телефон будет уже в приемлемом для автоматической обработки виде.

Answer (score 1):

Это, конечно, будет глупо, но можно привести сначала номер к строке, искать в нём ненужные символы, и затем их затирать, далее - к базе. Но повторюсь, это глупо.